# TableView creates duplicates cells

Tags: swift, firebase, uitableview, google-cloud-firestore

when the like button is tapped it should increase the number of likes on the cell thats related to it but im having an issue which it creates a totally new cell with the updated number of likes I believe the problem is coming from how im loading my cells I believe I also need to add the function remove() so it clears the old data after the snapshot listener takes effect but im not too sure

```
func loaddailymotivation() {
FirebaseReferece(.MotivationDAILY).addSnapshotListener { querySnapshot, error in

    guard let snapshot = querySnapshot else {
        print("Error fetching snapshots: \(error!)")
        return
    }

    snapshot.documentChanges.forEach { diff in
        if (diff.type == .added) { // this line means if the chage that happened in the document was equal to added something

            let data = diff.document.data()
              print("we have\(snapshot.documents.count) documents in this array")

              let dailyMotivationID = data["objectID"] as! String

              let dailymotivationTitle = data["Motivation title"] as! String //calls the data thats heald inside of motivation title in firebase
              let dailyMotivationScripture = data["daily motivation scripture"] as! String //calls the data thats heald inside of Motivation script in firebase

              let dailyMotivationNumberOfLikes = data["Number of likes in daily motivation post"]as! Int



             let MdataModel = motivationDailyModel(RealMotivationID: dailyMotivationID, RealmotivationTitle: dailymotivationTitle, RealmotivationScrip: dailyMotivationScripture, RealmotivationNumberOfLikes: dailyMotivationNumberOfLikes)

            self.motivationThoughts.append(MdataModel)

        }
        //===== //=====
        if (diff.type == .modified) {
            print("Modified data: \(diff.document.data())")

             let newdata = diff.document.data()

             let dailyMotivationID = newdata["objectID"] as! String

             let dailymotivationTitle = newdata["Motivation title"] as! String //calls the data thats heald inside of motivation title in firebase
             let dailyMotivationScripture = newdata["daily motivation scripture"] as! String //calls the data thats heald inside of Motivation script in firebase

            let dailyMotivationNumberOfLikes = newdata["Number of likes in daily motivation post"]as! Int


            let MdataModel = motivationDailyModel(RealMotivationID: dailyMotivationID, RealmotivationTitle: dailymotivationTitle, RealmotivationScrip: dailyMotivationScripture, RealmotivationNumberOfLikes: dailyMotivationNumberOfLikes)


            self.motivationThoughts.append(MdataModel)

            //  here you will receive if any change happens in your data add it to your array as you want
        }

        DispatchQueue.main.async {

            self.tableview.reloadData()
        }

    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both branches do exactly the same.

In the `modified` branch you have to get the corresponding object in `motivationThoughts`, update it and put it back, rather than creating a new object.

Something like

```
if diff.type == .modified {
    print("Modified data: \(diff.document.data())")
    let newdata = diff.document.data()

    let objectID = newdata["objectID"] as! String
    guard let dailymotivationIndex = motivationThoughts.firstIndex(where: {$0.dailyMotivationID == objectID}) else { return }

    var dailymotivation = self.motivationThoughts[dailymotivationIndex]
    let dailyMotivationNumberOfLikes = newdata["Number of likes in daily motivation post"] as! Int
    dailymotivation.RealmotivationNumberOfLikes = dailyMotivationNumberOfLikes
    self.motivationThoughts[dailymotivationIndex] = dailymotivation
}
```

And I recommend to reload only the row in the `modified` branch rather than the entire table view.

Comment: what does the   guard let dailymotivationIndex = motivationThoughts.firstIndex(where: {$0.dailyMotivationID == objectID}) else { return } do like what's its purpose

Comment: It's a safe way to return if the requested item is not in the array (well it should exist if your design is correct).

Comment: oh okay and in the self.motivationThoughts[index] = dailymotivation am I suppose to pass something inside of where index is? because I get the error Cannot convert value of type '(Any) -> Int' to expected argument type '(UnboundedRange_) -> ()'

Comment: My bad, please see the edit, it must be `self.motivationThoughts[dailymotivationIndex]`

Comment: Thank you so much! your a genius I've been trying to fix this for days and all my fixes have been producing other problems but yours worked